# On provability of false statements in constructive mathematics

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory, proof-theory, riemann-hypothesis, constructive-mathematics

Lagarias "elementary" reformulation of Robin's theorem is that $$\mathrm{RH}\iff\sigma(n)\leq H_n+e^{H_n}\log(H_n)$$
holds for every $n\geq 1$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors function and $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

1. Suppose under some axiom not provable in constructive mathematics (such as LPO or LLPO) we have that $\sigma(n)\leq H_n+e^{H_n}\log(H_n)$ (implication being true at every finite $n$). Then does it give RH or could there be another way to disprove RH if RH is false?
2. Do all equivalent statements to RH provide some explicit way for being not provable in constructive mathematics?

We can also form similar statement for $\mathrm P=\mathrm{NP}$ problem which states $$\exists c>0: \operatorname{NTIME}(n)\subseteq \operatorname{DTIME}(n^c)\implies \mathrm P=\mathrm{NP}.$$

3. Perhaps one can show under some axiom not provable in constructive mathematics (such as LPO or LLPO) we have that $\exists c>0: \operatorname{NTIME}(n)\subseteq \operatorname{DTIME}(n^c)$ (implication being true at every finite $n$). Would $\mathrm P$ not $\mathrm{NP}$ be still possible?

I am aware that LPO or LLPO possibly can fail. However if RH is false and/or $\mathrm P=\mathrm{NP}$ is false then would provability of such statements falsify LPO or LLPO in some sense (perhaps in some relevant topos)?

**Update $1$**

This has nothing to do with $\mathrm P\mathbin{!{=}}\mathrm{NP}$ or $\mathop!\mathrm{RH}$. I am interested about the hypothesis LPO or LLPO or suitable non-provable axioms in constructive mathematics in case such finitary $\mathrm P=\mathrm{NP}$ or RH or 'SomeProblem' can be proven (under unprovable axioms in constructivism) and if $\mathrm P\mathbin{!{=}}\mathrm{NP}$ and $\mathop!\mathrm{RH}$ and $\mathop!\mathrm{`SomeProblem'}$ is the truth.

> More broadly I ask would we proving LPO or LLPO or some suitable axiom is false in some relevant **topos** or probably even **unequivocally**?

**Update $2$**

Note certain statements that fall in above structure of provability such as $\mathrm P$ is $\mathrm{NP}$ are not known to be in $\mathrm{\Pi}_2^0$ ($\mathrm P$ not $\mathrm{NP}$ is known to be $\mathrm{\Pi}_2^0$ ([page $15$ in $\mathrm P$ $\stackrel{?}{=}$$\mathrm{NP}$ by Scott Aaronson](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf))).

Comment: There's little  in this question about P != NP or the Riemann Hypothesis. I suggest thinking through these issues with generic statements with the same number of quantifiers as a start. What do you get from general considerations?

Comment: Well it has nothing to do with P!=NP or !RH. I am just wondering about the hypothesis LPO or LLPO or suitable non-provable axioms in constructive mathematics in case such finitary P=NP or RH or 'SomeProblem' can be proven (under unprovable axioms in constructivism) and if P!=NP and !RH and !'SomeProblem' is the truth. More broadly I am wondering would we proving LPO or LLPO or some suitable axiom is false in some relevant topos or probably even unequivocally?

Comment: I find this question difficult to understand. As long as the non-constructive axioms are, like LPO and LLPO, true, so is everything you can prove from them. I suspect you meant to ask not about truth but rather about provability (or at least irrefutability) in some constructive system, but then you'd have to specify the system.  For instance, Bishop's constructive foundations are compatible with classical mathematics; Brouwer's aren't.

Comment: Other problems of similar flavor are Goldbach, Collatz, Twin Primes etc.

Comment: I think the statement $\operatorname{robin}(n)\equiv \sigma(n)\leq H_n + e^{H_n}\log(H_n)$ can be formulated in a primitive recursive fashion, so it is agnostic of just about any kind of foundations. Of course, $\forall n\,\operatorname{robin}(n)$ is a bit different in terms of provability, but still not ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to what I think to be your question (which isn't very clear to be honest):

For $RH$ and $P=NP$ I believe it makes no constructive difference if you use LPO (LLPO) or not.

According to Joe Shipman in a number of his FoM-postings, like [this one from March 2006](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2006-March/010113.html), the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to a $\Pi^0_1$ number-theoretic statement (which is automatically also $\Pi^0_2$) and $P=NP$ is equivalent to a $\Pi^0_2$ number-theoretic statement.

If Shipman is right (which I have no reason to doubt, but I cannot find a proof reference) this means they are both equivalent to $\Pi^0_2$ sentences phrased in Peano Arithmetic (**PA**).

We know however that **PA** is conservative over **HA**   (constructive Heyting Arithmetic) for $\Pi^0_2$ statements, that is **PA** proves the same $\Pi^0_2$ statements as **HA**.

That means that even as a constructive mathematician you can go ahead and use LPO and LLPO wildly (oh well, you can use all of excluded middle!), when trying to prove a $\Pi^0_2$ statement. The logicians have found a general way to eliminate excluded middle from such proofs.

Comment: I think P not NP is Pi_2^0. P is NP is perhaps Sigma_2^0.

The query is about LPO or LLPO or some unprovable axiom in constructive mathematics

1. invalidating statements in Pi_2^0 and 

2. validating statements in Sigma_2^0. 

Perhaps does PA prove same Sigma_2^0 sentences?

Comment: What is the general method to eliminate excluded middle? It appears that in certain topoi excluded middle is in valid. Is it possible there is such connection to such topoi and thus the proof just shows not not 'SomeStatement Q' which is different from 'SomeStatement Q'?